# Axes and the angle of $3\times 3$ rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, rotations

Given matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
1/3 & 2/3 & 2/3\\ 
-2/3 & -/3 & 2/3\\ 
2/3 & -2/3 & 1/3
\end{pmatrix}

I know, how to find angle by trace, but I'm really confused about revealing axis.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What happens to a point lying on the axis of the rotation?

Comment: It moves through the angle of rotation?..

Comment: The rotation axis is an eigen vector.

Comment: @KurtG. oh now I see, thank you! But I have another question: what if I have complex eigenvalues? Do they mean something or I can just throw them away?

Comment: @Noerig : You will ultimately throw them away. I was about to recommend you to read this [bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Determining_the_axis). However, even Wikipedia is not perfect. Do you see their typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\a{\beta}\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\p{\partial}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\cay#1{\operatorname{cay}\LR{#1}}
\def\skew#1{\operatorname{skew}\LR{#1}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
$A vector $b\in\bbR 3$ can be used to generate a skew matrix $B\in\bbR{3\times 3}\;$ (and vice versa)
$$\eqalign{
b &= \m{b_1\\b_2\\b_3}\qif B &= \m{
0 & -b_3 & b_2 \\
b_3 & 0 & -b_1 \\
-b_2 & b_1 & 0 \\} \\
}$$
$B$ has only one real eigenvalue $(\lambda=0),\,$ whose corresponding eigenvector is $b$
$$B\cdot b = 0$$

For a scalar variable, the Cayley Transform is defined as
$$\eqalign{
\cay{\a} &= \fracLR{\o-\a}{\o+\a} \\
}$$
When applied to an orthogonal matrix it produces a skew symmetric matrix
(and vice versa).

Applying the above operations to your rotation matrix yields
$$\eqalign{
B = \LR{I+R}^{-\o}\LR{I-R} = \m{
0 & -\o & 0 \\
\o & 0 & -\o \\
0 & \o & 0 \\}
\qiq b=\m{
\o \\ 0 \\ \o}
\\
}$$
It is easy to verify that $b$ is indeed the axis of rotation for $R$
$$\eqalign{
\LR{I \pm B}\cdot b &= b \\
R\cdot b &= \LR{I+B}^{-\o}\LR{I-B}\cdot b \\
 &= \LR{I+B}^{-\o}\cdot b \\
 &= b \\
}$$